# username and data not defined NodeJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to open `places.ejs` file by clicking the submit button on `show.js` page, just like the `show.ejs` page opens on clicking the submit button on `new.ejs` file, but a reference error is occurring. Please help me fix the error. I'm attaching herewith my routes.js code and a part of my index.js code Any help would be highly appreciable. Thank you

Here's my routes.js code

```
const { con, sessionStore } = require('./config/db');

exports.new = function (req, res) {
    message = '';
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        const post = req.body;
        const username = post.username;
        const title = post.title;
        const state = post.state;
        const category = post.category;
        const description = post.description;

        if (!req.files)
            return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

        const file = req.files.uploaded_image;
        var img_name = file.name;

        if (file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/gif") {

            file.mv('public/imgs/uploads/' + file.name, function (err) {

                var sql = "INSERT INTO `nt_data`(`username`,`title`,`state`,`category`, `images` ,`description`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                var query = con.query(sql, [username, title, state, category, img_name, description], function (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    if (!err) {
                        res.redirect('show/' + username + '/' + category);
                    }
                    else {
                        message = "This format is not allowed , please upload file with '.png','.gif','.jpg'";
                        res.render('new.ejs', { message: message });
                    }
                });
            });

        }
    }
    else {
        res.render('new');
    }
};



exports.show = function (req, res) {
    let message = '';
    con.query('SELECT * FROM nt_data WHERE username=? AND category=?', [req.params.username, req.params.category], (err, result) => {

        console.log(err)
        if (result.length <= 0) {

            message = "show not found!";

            res.render('show.ejs', { data: result, message: message });
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('places/' + username);
        }
    });
    res.render('show');
};
```

here's a part of my index.js code

```
app.get('/new', loginRequired, routes.new);
app.post('/', loginRequired, routes.new);


app.get('/show/:username/:category', loginRequired, routes.show);
app.post('/', loginRequired, routes.show);
app.get('/places/:username', loginRequired, routes.show);
```

error

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
ReferenceError: username is not defined
```

Comment: The username property is out of scope in the second module.exports.

Comment: please suggest how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: You should learn about variable scopes in JavaScript Instead of demanding a solution to one problem.

Answer (score 1):

In show function, you need to get username like this:

```
req.params.username
```

And for data I don't see where do you reference it, in witch line to do get an error?

Comment: check the line con.query in exports.show I've added req.params.username there

Comment: You need to do the same thing with res.redirect, in that line username is not defined.

Comment: can you please edit the code and share I'm not getting exactly where the changes are required

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @Soumya else block also needs req.params.username

Comment: I added req.params.username to the else but it shows the same error

Comment: @Soumya where else do you reference username? Check the line where the error message is thrown and then see how you reference username there. I'll need more info in order to help you with a code.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.show = function (req, res) {
    let message = '';
    con.query('SELECT * FROM nt_data WHERE username=? AND category=?', [req.params.username, req.params.category], (err, result) => {

        console.log(err)
        if (result.length <= 0) {

            message = "show not found!";

            res.render('show.ejs', { data: result, message: message });
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('places/' + req.params.username); // Change here
        }
    });
    res.render('show');
};
```

Comment: I made the changes but it's still showing  the error